# Reading from database says No such table

Tags: android

I am trying to read data from a db stored in assets folder.
The table name is quest.
When the execution reaches Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null) this line I am getting the error : "no such table :quest"
My table looks like this
[image]
Kindly help me.

```
     public void CopyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException{
       InputStream in  = ctx.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
       Log.e("sample", "Starting copying" );
       String outputFileName = DATABASE_PATH+DATABASE_NAME;
       File databaseFile = new File( "/data/data/com.example.questionsdb/databases");
        // check if databases folder exists, if not create one and its subfolders
        if (!databaseFile.exists()){
            databaseFile.mkdir();
        }

       OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       int length;


       while ((length = in.read(buffer))>0){
              out.write(buffer,0,length);
       }
       Log.e("sample", "Completed" );
       out.flush();
       out.close();
       in.close();

    }
public void openDataBase () throws SQLException{
    Log.e("Start", "openDataBase" );

       String path = DATABASE_PATH+DATABASE_NAME;
       dbase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
       Log.e("openDataBase", "Completed" );
    }

 public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
    Log.e("Add Start", "msg:getAllQuestions");
    List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
    dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Question quest = new Question();
            quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
            quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
            quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
            quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
            quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
            quest.setOPTD(cursor.getString(6));
            quest.setREFTEXT(cursor.getString(7));
            quesList.add(quest);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    Log.e("Add End", "msg:getAllQuestions");
    // return quest list
    return quesList;
}
```

Comment: Does the db have a table names quest?  Capitalization matters.  I notice your openDatabase call has createIfNeeded flag-  if it creates a new one it won't have any tables in it

Comment: Where are you Creating your table? Where are the CREATE TABLE statements?

Comment: @ joao2fast4u The table exist in the database stored in the assets folder.

Comment: @ Gabe Sechan : I have uploaded my table screen shot , opend through sqlite data browser

Comment: You have to copy your database to your internal app-folder databases/ to read from it. Did you checked if the database file is there after you create it?

Comment: @joao2fast4u Hi can you let me know how to check if the database file exist? Thanks

Comment: @user3680860 Yes, if you have your phone rooted, you can get directly to the databases folder and check if the file is there. Otherwise you can check if your dbase object is not null after calling openDatabase().

Comment: I can see the db getting created in databases folder...But while executing the code, I noted that in CopyDataBaseFromAsset() , out.write(buffer,0,length) line never gets executed and hence there are no data in the db created in databases folder...is this the root cause..

Answer (score 0):

This is only a guess but I can see three possible things are happening here...

Calling this.getReadableDatabase() in your createDatabase() method is automatically creating an empty database.
Your attempt to copy your pre-created database from your assets folder is failing or the database is being copied to the wrong place.
The empty database created in step 1 (above) is the one that is being queried when you call db.rawQuery(...) from your main code.
To explain further it is usefult to look at the source for SQLiteOpenHelper

When you create an instance of SQLiteOpenHelper it sets things like the database name and version but it does not create the database. Instead, the first call to either getReadableDatabase() or getWritableDatabase() checks to see if the database exists and if it doesn't it creates it. After creating the empty database, the onCreate(...) method is called which, in your case, does nothing.

On to point 2 (above) - you say that DB_PATH is /data/data/mypackagename/databases. If that is really the case and you have no trailing / then the line...

String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
...will set myPath to /data/data/mypackagename/databasesligas_db. In that case, even if the copy from assets succeeds, the copied database isn't going to be where you expect it to be.

Finally on point 3 (above) when you call db.rawQuery(...) the instance that db points to is returned by the previous call to getWritableDatabase(). Assuming the copy from assets has failed or that it has been copied to the incorrect path, db will be pointing at the empty database created in step 1.

The error you get is that the table doesn't exist and it isn't an error indicating the database doesn't exist - the only logical explanation is that it's performing a query on an empty database and not the one that has been copied from assets.

One other thing I meant to mention. It isn't a good idea to use hard-coded paths to any of the Android directories. For example - although on most devices, the directory where databases are created will be /data/data//databases this is not a guarantee. It is much safer if you call the getDatabasePath(...) method as it will return a File object which can be used to get the path to the databases directory used by the Android database classes.

Answer (score 0):

The db file I was using was not proper. Then I follwed the details under the link http://pranayairan.tumblr.com/post/30319261303/shipping-sqllite-db-with-your-app 
to create db.
After that I am able to copy db to my databases folder under data\data.
Thanks